# Images not showing after upgrade Typo3 version 7 to Typo3 version 9 manually

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have upgrade Typo3 version 7 to Typo3 version 9 manually. Everything is working fine except Images.

Image showing path

```
download/sdl-eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1ODUxMjMzMjAsImV4cCI6MTU4NTE3MDExNiwidXNlciI6MCwiZ3JvdXBzIjpbMCwtMV0sImZpbGUiOiJmaWxlYWRtaW5cL19wcm9jZXNzZWRfXC8yXC9kXC9jc21fZmFjaGdyb3NzaGFlbmRsZXJfNTFiZDNkZDJmNS5qcGciLCJwYWdlIjozOTJ9.iO2xSjzrqdf_3-hgUrZh48Q-eagWGcwc8DoiZl3Z9po/csm.jpg
```

And in admin panel -> files it is showing some overlay icon. Kindly help me fix this issue. Thanks in advance

[image: filelist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any of the securedownloads extensions? https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=secure+downloads? The installation would require some changes to .htaccess.
I hope this helps you tracking down the problem.

Comment: Yes I am using Secure Download (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/secure_downloads) extensions. I tried the htaccess code mentioned in their documentation but issue still same. Kindly share if you have any other httacess code. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please follow their instructions for installation and configuration. You can configure it the way you want.

Comment: Thank you for help. My issue resolved with the settings.